# WSO2 JMS One-way request with replyTo

Tags: jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to set up a JMS sender and a JMS receiver in different instances. I am trying to set up the replyTo queue, but once I set up OUT_ONLY=true, the replyTo header is not set up in the JMS message.

Is there any way to configure the replyTo queue, per sequence, without waiting for the reply?

Thanks in advance.
Ramon

Answer (score 0):

In Case anybody is still interested (and since the wso2 folk seem to never be around to provide any support here) I manage to eventually stumble on an answer (I have raised a simialr question) in an old obscure jira defect where it happens to be mentioned.

the sequence should set a couple of properties like so prior to the send mediator.

```
<property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default"
   type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property action="set" name="JMSReplyTo"
   scope="transport" type="STRING" value="yourqueuename"/>
```

yourqueuename will be prefixed by queue:// by synapse so dont worry with any of that, just the name is fine (and if it doesnt exist, the loveliness that is jms will create it for you). Also note the scope of the property is "transport".

hope that was useful to somebody else, it sure took me the best part of a day to stumble on the answer.

thanks Paul